# How to delete entire row if row contain "abc xyz" using excel operation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have excel file. i need to delete entire row if row value contain "abc xyz".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0BCT.png)

Answer (score 1):

### Delete Filtered Rows

- Select the whole 'table' range including headers.
- Filter the range by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
- Click on the filter's drop-down arrow of the appropriate column.
- In the drop-down menu, uncheck *Select All*, check *abc xyz* and press *OK*.
- Select the row headings (1,2,3,4,...) of the filtered rows actually selecting the entire rows.
- Right-click anywhere in the selection and in the appearing menu choose *Delete Row*.
- Remove the filter by again using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: Can we use excel formula directly, if there is  any?

Comment: You can delete rows only manually or by using `VBA`.

Comment: Please can you share VBA for the same.

Comment: i tired this one =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$3:$A$7,1,FALSE)),"Keep","Delete"), but not working

Comment: Try `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A$3:A$7,0)),"Delete","Keep")`